# Configuring WCF in IIS7 & Windows 7

Tags: wcf, iis-7, windows-7, uac

I am having a problem when I try to browse WCF service (.svc file) which is hosted in IIS7 & Windows7. It throws following error.

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

I tried to run ServiceModelReg, but it say I should have admin rights in order to run this, although I am admin on this machine.

Does any one know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please don't use a signature block on your posts on here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FInally....

I am able to resolve this issue.

I ran following two command and it solved the problem.

aspnet_regiis -i & ServiceModelReg -i

Even though I am admin on the machine, I need to run this 2 commands by right click and select 'Run as Admin'.

Comment: @VeeKayBee you probably just need to run these from the right directory, depending on your .net version.  ie run from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Answer (score 3):

Your issued is answered [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1418819.aspx). Trying to be short:

> When you start the command prompt, can
>   you right-click on the icon to open it
>   and select "Run as Administrator"? I
>   don't know exactly what's the logic
>   behind that, but on Vista there are
>   two kinds of administrative users, one
>   "normal" administrator and one
>   "elevated" administrator. I'd guess
>   the tool needs the second kind.

and second

> Also, Why do you need to run
>   Servicemodelreg.exe on VIsta?
>   Officially this is not supported on
>   Vista. Instead you can go to WIndows
>   features menu throught Add remove
>   programs and enabled Http Activation
>   under .Net framework 3.0 feature.
>
> This will enable everything you might
>   want to do via Servicemodelreg.exe.

**Edit**

And also [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/07/21/running-a-wcf-service-on-iis-7.aspx).
[image]

Comment: Restuta, I am not running this no VISTA, I am running this on Windows 7 Professional. Also I tried to run this by right clicking and 'Run As Admin', but no luck with that also

Comment: This is the same for Windows 7, have you tried shown solution?

Comment: I tried your suggession, after this change I am getting following error.

HTTP 400 Bad Request - The webpage cannot be found

Any idea what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into IIS Manager and double click on Handler Mappings do you have *.svc paths listed?

If they are missing this link may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252(v=vs.90).aspx